# How to host the Microsoft Bot Framework Composer application as an Azure Web App

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-web-app-service, botframework

Hey Stack Overflow community,

i would like to host the [Microsoft Bot Framework Composer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/composer/introduction?tabs=v2x) as an Azure Web App to access it via web, but unfortunately I don't know exactly how. I have already seen in the documentations that the whole thing has been [implemented as a Linux VM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/composer/how-to-host-composer), but not yet as an App Service. Reasons for this are for example easier management of the instances. Does anyone have an approach or solution if this can be implemented and if so how?

The Bot Framework Composer itself is an open source tool based on the Bot Framework SDK. It is available as a [desktop application](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-Composer#get-started) as well as a [web-based component](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-Composer#build-composer-locally). Right here I want to use the functionality as a web-based component to make the instance available online. Here you can find the included [code to the Composer](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-Composer).

**Prerequisites for running the Bot Framework Composer**

- NodeJs LTS 14.x
- Yarn
- .Net Core SDK 3.1 or later
- On Windows, install the latest Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015, 2017 and 2019

**Steps to do this on your local machine (with PowerShell)**

```bash
git clone https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-Composer.git
cd BotFramework-Composer
cd Composer # switch to Composer folder
yarn install # install dependencies
yarn build # build extensions and libs
yarn startall # start client and server at the same time
```

I would greatly appreciate any technical guidance, tutorials, or resources related to deploying Microsoft Bot Framework Composer instance on an Azure Web App. Thank you for your valuable assistance!

Comment: I don't think there's much out there. There is this doc, but it's archived: [https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-Composer/blob/main/docs/archived%20docs/Deploying-Composer.md](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-Composer/blob/main/docs/archived%20docs/Deploying-Composer.md)